# Using IF condition to populate a new sheet in Google App Script Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet containing 2 sheets.

If the content of a specific cell in sheet 1 is equal to something, I want to write something in a specific cell of the sheet 2.

As I need to do it a lot of times, I want to do it using Google App Script. Using VBA, this is super easy, but here it returns me that I "*can't change or modify the properties of the object*". Do you have any idea of what's wrong with my code?

Thank you for your help !

Here is my code :

```
function synthese() {

var results = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('results');

var synthese = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('synt');

  B3 = results.getRange("B3");

  if (B3="Yes") {
    results.getRange("A1").setValue = "Yes";
  } else {
    results.getRange("A1").setValue = "No";
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

B3 is still a range, with properties such as size, background color, etc.
It is not a value, you can extract that via `getValue()`.

Your second problem is that you are doing an assignment in the if.

Lastly `setValue` is a method not an attribute, so the value needs to be supplied as an argument.

```
function synthese() {
  var results = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('results');
  var synthese = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('synt');
  var B3 = results.getRange("B3"); // good practice to make variables local

  if (B3.getValue() === "Yes") {
    results.getRange("A1").setValue("Yes");
  } else {
    results.getRange("A1").setValue("No");
  } 
}
```

Comment: Wow, so much mistakes... I still need to learn a lot of things, JS is really different from VBA. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Happy to help. If this solved your problem can you please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks